# How to automatically move strings of table cells to new line?

Tags: tables, longtable, longtabu

I have the following LaTeX long table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}

\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=25mm}
\geometry{bottom=35mm}
\geometry{left=35mm}
\geometry{right=20mm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|}
\caption{--- Caption of long table.}\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Data} & \multirow{2}{*}{Some long string, title of second column of table.} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Some long string, title of third column of table.} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Coefficients} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rates of growth, \%} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rate of increase, \%} \\ \cline{3-10} 
& & chain & base & chain & base & chain & base & chain & base \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\hline
%
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Continuation below\ldots} \
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 

\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see on the picture, text of the second column (first row) is displayed on 3rd and 4th colums. And the fourth column is excessively stretched.
I need that the first row is automatically increased in height. And strings in 1st and 2nd rows automatically moved to new line. That there were no stretched columns.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! try `\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|>{\small}X|}` if helps.

Comment: I have: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (�): `c' used. ...​{\small}X|>{\small}X‌​|>{\small}X|}

Comment: Please help us help you and edit your minimal working example. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I edited the whole question. I inserted the missing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I surely can find better ways to waste my time,</strike> (not politically correct) but here we go with this completely impossible table (at 14pt document pointsize ...)

Use capt-of or whatever to add a caption.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}

\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=25mm}
\geometry{bottom=35mm}
\geometry{left=35mm}  % you really want left ≠ right ?
\geometry{right=20mm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{\FOO}{p{\dimexpr.09\linewidth}}

\noindent\kern-1.5cm\rotatebox{90}{\small
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{\FOO|}p{\dimexpr.14\linewidth}|*{3}{\FOO|}}
\hline
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\parbox{2.5cm}{\footnotesize \RaggedRight \strut Some long
    string, title of third column of table.\strut}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Coefficients} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rates of growth, \%} 
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr.18\linewidth}|}{Rate of\par increase, \%} 
\\ \cline{3-10} 
Data
&\smash{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\footnotesize Some long
    string, title of second column of table.\baselineskip12pt}}
&&&&&&&&\\
&&chain&base&chain&base&chain&base&chain&base\\
&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}

\clearpage

\noindent\kern-1.5cm\rotatebox{90}{\small
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{\FOO|}p{\dimexpr.14\linewidth}|*{3}{\FOO|}}
\hline
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 &
0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\\hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and page 2

[image]

---

Second attempt. It holds on one page... (once we squeeze the 10 columns into the available width...)

This second one uses longtable, I removed the caption at some point, it can be put back.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}

\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=25mm}
\geometry{bottom=35mm}
\geometry{left=35mm}  % you really want left ≠ right ?
\geometry{right=20mm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{\FOO}{p{\dimexpr.05\linewidth}}


Some text.

{\tiny
\begin{longtable}{|*{6}{\FOO|}p{\dimexpr.085\linewidth}|*{3}{\FOO|}}
\hline
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\RaggedRight \strut Some long
    string, title of third column of table.\baselineskip8pt\strut}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Coefficients} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rates of growth, \%} 
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr.1\linewidth}|}{Rate of\par increase, \%} 
\\ \cline{3-10} 
Data
&\raisebox{10pt}{\smash{\parbox[c]{0.8cm}{\RaggedRight Some long
    string, title of second column of table.\strut\baselineskip8pt}}}
&&&&&&&&\\
&&chain&base&chain&base&chain&base&chain&base\\
&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 &
                                                                           0,2990 & 0,2990 \\
%%%
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 &
0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\ 
0,5762 & 0,4353 & 0,3631 & 0,2992 & 0,299 & 0,2993 & 0,36384912 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 & 0,2990 \\\hline
\end{longtable}

}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: "you really want left ≠ right ?" Yes. Thank You!

Comment: Difficult code.

Comment: I think there are better ways; but first I had to understand you had high fontsize and many columns, hence use of \tiny. I suggest you unaccept my answer because there are table experts around here which will do it better.